# Mapping folder to different folder on the same Apache Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mapping

I have My old domain on my server **myexample.com** with folder name "**myexample**" and a have different domain **mymaindomain.com**, What i am looking is whenever user opens **mymaindomain.com/contest** it opens the site that is in "**myexample**" folder and still keep the url in address bar **mymaindomain.com/contest/whatever.xxx** using htaccess or httpd on apache server.

Comment: Are both domains and their DocumentRoot same?

Comment: Both domains are mapped on different folder in same Root root folder!
/public_html/myexample
/public_html/contest

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
Alias /contest /public_html/myexample
```

in the virtual host definition for myexample.com.  Note though, that this may cause links in your content to be wrong if they expect to be located at / instead of at /contest.

Comment: Is this with apache htaccess or Tomcat server? How do i do that i tomcat server?

Comment: With Apache.  I don't know about Tomcat.  Is it the same?  Your question title says Apache, so if it's Tomcat, you should say that, or at least tag the question as Tomcat.